# React useContext method scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I create custom hooks for reading state stores in my applications.
`const store = useStore();`
Which I define as:

```
const store = new Store();

const StoreContext = createContext(store);
StoreContext.displayName = "StoreContext";

function useStore(): Store {
  const context = useContext(StoreContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useStore must be used within MyProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export { store, useStore };
```

Store itself is almost always a class with multiple fields and methods.
Let's say I define it with example methods:

```
export class Store {
  /** Here is some other code with constructor, methods, fields etc... */
  public doSomething() { return this.doSomthingElse() };
  private doSemothingElse() { console.log("done something else")};
}
```

Why is it that when I use my hook like this with destructuring:
`const { doSomething } = useStore();`
I get `can not read property doSomethingElse of undefined`
meaning `this` is `undefined`, that way.
But when I do:
`const store = useStore(); store.doSomething();`
It works just fine?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#this_in_classes

Comment: Ok, so it turns out binding `this` for `doSomething` fixes scope issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It works that way due to `this` behaviour in JS classes. Binding calling method to this inside a constructor solves the issue with `undefined` context within a hook.

```
this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
```

Kudos to `Gabriele Petrioli` for giving explanation.